# Cannot create activex component 64 bit on Win64bit?

Tags: .net, vb.net, adobe-illustrator

I install Illustrator 64 bit on Win7 64bit.

```
Dim oIlls = CreateObject("Illustrator.Application.CS6")
```

Occur Exception: `Cannot create ActiveX component.`

If use Illustrator 32 bit. It can CreateObject ok.
But i want try use Illustrator 64 bit. but can't CreateObject .

How can CreateObject of component 64 bit?

Comment: compile code only for x64 platform

Comment: Is there the progid in the registry? have you tried "Illustrator.Application" progid? i cant find the progid you're using in the illustrator for vbscript manual ( http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/illustrator/scripting/cs6/Illustrator-Scripting-Reference-VBScript.pdf )

Comment: if you start a bounty, you should at least answer at the comments..., or should i install illustrator to check by myself?

Answer (score 4):

Your application is obviously running as 32 bit or the error would occur the other way around. You should either set the "Target CPU" to either "Any CPU" or "x64" if you don't plan on supporting 32 bit OS.

[Depending on the version of VS] Open "Project Properties", click the "Compile" tab, then change the "Target CPU".

Comment: I setting to "Any CPU" , but it still can't start application

Comment: Assuming that means, "you are getting the same error in the same place", then the only thing left is that "Illustrator.Application.CS6" is not valid on the computer you are trying it on. Check the registry.